# Automatically update an ID label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I am working on making a label inside my Windows Form to display new ID automatically. My label was connected to an access database and I want to make the label to display new ID after the last record of ID inside my database. For example, the last record is 'tt0005061' from Movie table. The label should display a new ID, 'tt0005062'.

```
Public Class Movies_Registration_Form
 Dim index As Integer = 0

Private Sub Movies_Registration_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 showData(index)
End Sub

Public Sub showData(position As Integer)
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=1MDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        strSQL = "SELECT RIGHT(tconst,7) From Movie ORDER BY tconst DESC"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        da.Fill(table)
        lblMovieID.Text = "tt" & table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
    End Sub
```

The output of the label should be in an increment form, meaning that it should be +1 from the last record inside my database.

Comment: Did you tried to add one to the value retrieved from database?

Comment: That's my question, I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Assume that value is of type string (because you are using RIGTH method on the value), but contains only digits, then convert string to int, add one and format result in the way you need to display

Comment: can u write the code for me? I am new to visual basic ^_^!!

Comment: Sorry, I can not write code for you, this is your job ;). But I will be glad to advise you. For example google 1. how to parse string to integer, 2. How to convert/format integer to string with prefixed zeros (zeros on the left)

Comment: Alright, thx for the help, really appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
lblMovieID.Text = (Integer.Parse(table.Rows(0)(0)) + 1).ToString("tt0000000")
```